# Facebook API PHP SDK - How to request Email and Gender

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**Hi Stackers,**

I'm having a small problem, and I didn't find a working solution on Stackoverflow about this. It's all about the Facebook API. I've created a Login with Facebook function on a site, and this works fine. However, I need to get the Email adress and Gender of the user. This is in the basic_profile permissions, but I can't find how to request it, so that I can use it as a variable.

**fb-callback.php**

```
    /* INCLUSION OF LIBRARY FILEs*/
require_once( 'facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once( 'facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once( 'facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once( 'facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( 'facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
/* USE NAMESPACES */

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

session_start();

// Facebook info
//2.Use app id,secret and redirect url
$app_id = '';
$app_secret = '';
$redirect_url='';

//3.Initialize application, create helper object and get fb sess
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
$sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

//4. if fb sess exists echo name
if(isset($sess)) {
    //create request object,execute and capture response
    $request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/me');

    // from response get graph object
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    // use graph object methods to get user details
    $name= $graph->getName();

    $_SESSION["fb_access_token"] = $sess;

    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/account.php">';
     exit("Please wait... If you do not get redirected <a href='/account.php'>click here</a>.");

}else{
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    //header("Location: " . $loginUrl);


    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='. $loginUrl .'">';
 exit("Please wait... If you do not get redirected <a href='". $loginUrl ."'>click here</a>.");

}
```

What I need is a way to get the Email and Gender of this user, so that I can put it in two variables, `$email` and `$gender`

Does someone have any idea? Do I overlook something?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi has a simple example. (It asks for the fields id and name only there, but that should be easy enough to modify accordingly.)

Comment: Although it looks like you are using the PHP SDK v4 there - the current version is v5, and all the examples in the documentation are for v5 as well. Recommend that you upgrade to the current version.